# Horizontally Center a <div> that is not fixed

Tags: css, html

I want to horizontally center a column in a responsive grid I'm trying to make.  I have the grid set up, and it works just fine.  But I want to make a .class that will take a column and center it horizontally in the parent (`.row`).  I would use this class to take a one-column-row and center the column in said row.  I can center the text using the `text-align` property, but I want the entire column to be centered that way if I add a border/background to the column it will be centered in the row, not just the column's content.

Here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yglFn/).

Comment: Couldn't you simply set `margin: auto` to get the column centered?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are setting a width on the column, simply use `margin:0 auto` to center it. You would need to overwrite `float:left` with `float:none` though..

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bHlum/)

```
.center {
    text-align: center;
    margin:0 auto;
    float:none;
}
```

Alternatively, if the element *doesn't* have a fixed width set on it, you could simply make it an `inline-block` element and add `text-align:center` to the parent. Perfect for dynamically varying widths.

Comment: This works perfectly.  Thank you Josh!  I obviously was overlooking the fact that I had `float:left` set the the columns.